# How to I get the third box to go under the first box and not in the middle?

Tags: php, flexbox

Image of the boxes: 
[Boxes stacked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcUiE.png)

My question is. How do I get this third box to go under the first box and not in the center, but I also need everything to be in the center of the page.

Comment: If you expand with the scroll, they are all on same line.

Answer (score 0):

You can either resort to flex or do change the display property , so ideally you should have code like below

```
.test li {
       border: 1px solid black;
       /*display: inline-block; change this to block*/
       display: block;
       float: left;
       font-size: 20px;
       list-style-type: none;
       width: 150px;
       height: 150px;
       line-height: 30px;
       padding-left: 1px;
       padding-right: 1px;
       margin: 15px 25px;
       text-align: center;
       border-radius: 5%;
       background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.test {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -200px;
}

ul {
    position: relative;
}

.test li {
  display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid black;
font-size: 20px;
list-style-type: none;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
line-height: 30px;
padding-left: 1px;
padding-right: 1px;
margin: 15px;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 5%;
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}

li:nth-child(3) {
  display: block;
  left: 100px;
  bottom: 200px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="test">
   <ul>
      <li>test1</li>
      <li>test2</li>
      <li>test3</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```